# Content type and templates

Tags: 2010, content-type, document-template, wiki-pages

I am a developer trying to find a SharePoint OOTB  equivelent for a "has a" relationship. I  beleiev what Im looking for is a content type template, so that everytime i create an item of from this template it automatically knows to add a couple diffrent document templates and a wiki library associated with it... so i have a couple questions on how to do this.

1. Can a wiki library be added as part of a content type
2. How do i associate document templates to a content type

Answer (score 1):

A content type defines which columns are included in a list or library item. Content types can be defined at the site level, site collection level, or in a centralized Content Type Hub if  the Managed Metadata Service is running.

I believe what you are after is rather a site template: Create a site, add lists, libraries. Add content types to the list and libraries.

Save the site as a template and it will be available in the Solutions Gallery and can be used to create new sites with exactly the properties of the template.

So, re `1. Can a wiki library be added as part of a content type` - No. That question does not make sense.

Re `2. How do i associate document templates to a content type` - Edit the content type and in the Advanced options for the content type provide the URL of a document template or upload a new document template.